# Have any RPGs used an Action Point system?

Tags: combat, homebrew, game-design, actions

Are there any RPG systems out there that handle Action Points, or Time Units? Instead of having simple action types, handling turns more like Xcom UFO Defense or Xenonauts. If so, what are the main problems with the system? What are ways to improve the action economy in this system?

Comment: The basic answer is “yes”, but since this site is bad for questions that turn into giant lists of answers, to find out which games makes that “yes” true and then talk about their virtues and vices you will want to try [one of these RPG discussion forums](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5449/321) (which don't share this site's problem with long list threads).